# String format response from jersey server , instead of JSON format

Tags: jersey-2.0

The current output is

```
 "some-details":
            [
                "{detail-1={date=17/04/2017}, subdetails=[]}",
                "{detail-2={date=17/04/2017}, subdetails=[{subdetail1=ABC}, {subdetail2=DEF}]}"
            ]
```

The value for some-details is taken as a List where Object is Map

We are using jersey server and have used @xmlElement on some-details , the details within the key some-details cannot have pojo as its is dynamic.

The expected output is

```
    "some-details":
                [
                    "detail-1":{ "date" = "17/04/2017" }, "subdetails" : []}",
                    "detail-2":{"date":"17/04/2017"}, "subdetails"=  ["subdetail1" : "ABC",
 "subdetail2" : "DEF" 
]}
                ]
```

Can anyone help with this.what other alternatives can be tried out

Project dependencies :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxrs.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jersey 2.19 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId> 
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
     <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you using Jackson as the JSON provider? Jackson wouldn't have this problem. For better help, please post some code and your project dependencies.

Comment: switch to jersey-media-json-jackson and get rid of jersey-media-moxy

Comment: You can put @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) with resource(service) method.